mysqli rollback commit is not working with innodb table
I am trying to set up transaction rollbacks but no matter what I do, the insert is not rolled back.
I have confirmed the DB engine is innoDB:
Name                            Engine  Version     Row_format  
order_fulfillment_discounts     InnoDB    10         Dynamic

I initially tried adding it the real queries but began pairing it down when that was not working. What was left is the most dirt simple code:
$dbConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dealers");

$dbConnect->autocommit(false);
$dbConnect->begin_transaction();

$dbConnect->query("INSERT INTO order_fulfillment_discounts (fulfillment_id, order_id, discount_id, discount_type, discount_category) VALUES (1,1,1,'foo','test')");
$dbConnect->commit();
$dbConnect->rollback();

That is the entirety of the code, there are no files being required and nothing else making a connection.
The commit works fine, I can debug and see that the insert does not occur until commit() is called so I know transactions in general are working. The result of the commit is TRUE and the result of the rollback is also TRUE.
I am running this on localhost on a Mac using PHP 8 with Homebrew. Is there a possibility that it is a setting/permission that prevents rollbacks for safety?
The root DB user has all the permissions and I even added a password to the database to see if that would help.
I have run it both in phpstorm and in a browser.
I have debugged it so there is time between commit and rollback as well as running it with a sleep().
I have tried specifying a transaction name.
Everything works the same, the commit always works as expected and the rollback does not.

You can't do both a commit and a rollback, both will end the transaction completely.

Rollback is not an undo, it's an abort. You can't rollback after commit because commit writes the pending transaction, completing it. You rollback instead of commit. In your code, you're calling rollback at a point where a transaction is no longer pending, so there is nothing to do.
